# How do I interpolate a variable into a string?

Tags: python

I have a username, "jerry" that I want to check if it's in my airtable's Username column:

```
username = 'jerry'
rows = at.get_all(formula="FIND('jerry', {Username})=1") # I want to replace the `jerry` there with the `username` var
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3.6+ offers string interpolation with [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), which should be the preferred way of doing this.

So something like this should work:

```
username = 'jerry'
rows = at.get_all(formula=f"FIND('{username}', {{Username}})=1")
```

Notice the double curly braces to escape them in the string.

Comment: Be aware, though, that this assumes that `username` itself does not contain unescaped single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in modern Python is to do:

```
foo = 12
bar = 'hello'
print(f"Giving {foo} {bar}'s")
```

Note the `f` in front of the string literal, making it a "f-string" where substitution will take place.

Answer (score -2):

I believe if you put a .str in before the parentheses the variable is in could do something maybe.
---.str('words')

hope this helps.